# Математическая последовательность

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать такой массив из 10 чисел, чтобы не было чисел, разность между которыми была равна разности их позиций, ИЛИ которые равны. Например [1,2]-не подходит, [4,10,11]-не подходит, [1,3,5,7,9]-подходит. Все числа должны быть ЦЕЛЫМИ, ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНЫМИ, МИНИМАЛЬНЫМИ подходящими.
[js]. Код ниже почему-то не решает проблему.

```
var d=0;
var k=0;
var arr=[];//Список чисел
var i=0;//Позиция нового числа
var j=0;//Не должно быть диагоналей в 45 градусов между j,arr[j] и i,k  
while(i<10){
    k=0;
    j=0;
    while(j<arr.length){
        d=Math.abs((arr[j]-k)/(i-j));//Коэффициент линии
        if(d==0||d==1){//Проверка
            k++;//Проверяем новое число
        }
        j++;
    }
    arr.push(k);
    i++;
}//->[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, задача в том, чтобы отсортировать имеющийся массив, чтобы соседние числа отличались более чем на 1?  Или нужно сгенерировать новый массив от некоего начального числа (с приростом 2)?

Comment: Первый элемент -0.  Не должно быть [...x,(n-1 numbers),(x+n)...]. N-й элемент не должен отличаться от P-ого элемента на разность N и P.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy числа не могут быть равными

Comment: Задача о размещении ферзей.